# 50 === 50: false. 50 == 50: true?

Tags: javascript

I'm at a total loss.

I have a function..

```
Number.prototype.abs = function () {
    return this >= 0 ? this : this * -1;
};
```

..that returns the absolute value of a number..

```
(50).abs(); // 50
(-50).abs(); // 50
```

..but that doesn't compare correctly..

```
(50).abs() === 50; // False
```

..sometimes.

```
(50).abs() == 50; // True
(-50).abs() === 50; // True
```

The thing about it, is that it works in Chrome 12, and Firefox 4, but not in IE 9, Safari 5, or Opera 11.

I don't see anything wrong with the code, and since it works in Chrome and Firefox, it's something browser specific but I don't know what.

**Update:** The browser specific difference is strict mode support. I run my code in strict mode, which introduces some changes that make my code work. The reason it failed in the browsers it did, is because they have an incomplete or missing strict mode.

Why is it returning false?

Comment: You realize `===` is a *strict* equality check. Meaning the types on each side must also match.

Comment: No repro here... but a larger question:  Why aren't you using Math.abs()?

Comment: @John I just wanted quicker access, so I wrote my own.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Even though [Jeremy Heiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039265/50-50-false-50-50-true/6039320#6039320) is correct, his justification is misconstrued. Why you're getting `object` instead of `number` has nothing to do with constructors.

The problem here is the `this` keyword. You need to understand what happens whenever you use `this`. A little bit of digging through the ECMA draft will show you that

> The this keyword evaluates to the value of the ThisBinding of the current execution context.

(I would change the above. The `this` keyword doesn't evaluate to the **value** of anything as we'll soon see.) Hmm, okay, but how exactly does `ThisBinding` work? Read on!

> The following steps are performed when
>   control enters the execution context
>   for function code contained in
>   function object F, a caller provided
>   thisArg, and a caller provided
>   argumentsList:
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 2. Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the
>      global object.
> 3. **Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to**
>        **ToObject(thisArg).**
> 4. Else set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 5. Let localEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment
>      passing the value of the [[Scope]]
>      internal property of F as the
>      argument.
> 6. Set the LexicalEnvironment to localEnv.
> 7. Set the VariableEnvironment to localEnv.
> 8. Let code be the value of F’s [[Code]] internal property.
> 9. Perform Declaration Binding Instantiation using the function code
>      code and argumentList as described in 10.5

And therein lies the rub (look at the bolded part). If a function is ever called from a non-object context, `ThisBinding` (aka using `this`) always returns the value of the context wrapped inside an object. The easiest way to fix it would be to do:

```
Number.prototype.abs = function () {
    "use strict"; // if available
    // * 1 implicitly coerces 'this' to a number value
    return this >= 0 ? this * 1 : this * -1;
    //... or Number(this) explicitly coerces 'this' to its toNumber value
    return Number(this >= 0 ? this : this * -1);
};
```

...to coerce the `this` object (or to force strict mode). But I think it's important to understand how `this` works, and this question is a great example of that.

Comment: Wow.. Depth.. And I thought Jeremy's answer was overkill. xD I like your answer more, because you supplied a fix, and explained why it works now. `this = new AcceptedAnswer();`

Comment: It's okay, Jeremy got all the rep ;]

Comment: @David With all the up votes, he got plenty. xD Also, happy late birthday.

Comment: All is fair when getting to the means of What The Hell(tm) JavaScript is doing!

Comment: @Jeremy It's a great language, but it definitely does have it's moments.

Comment: From this excellent answer follows that using `strict` would also solve your problem ;-)

Comment: @Kooilnc, which is actually the "correct" way of fixing it. Updated.

Comment: @David I already use strict mode, which is why it worked in Chrome and Firefox. It didn't work in others, because strict mode support is still very limited and/or nonexistent. Your old code was better.

Comment: @David Titarenco - `this` **does** have a value, it is a reference to an object. But you are otherwise correct - the OPs code will return a Number object where the value is +ve and a primitive where it is -ve. A simple fix is: `return Math.abs(this);`.

Comment: @RobG, I guess it would be more correct to say it's not *a value*, but the terminology in the spec is confusing (unless we want to stipulate a difference between value of a value and value of an object - a distinction that sould be made in the "The `this` object" section imo).

Comment: @David - ECMA-262 §11.1.2 Identifier Reference `An Identifier is evaluated using the scoping rules stated in section 10.1.4. The result of evaluating an Identifier is always a value of type Reference.` So if you want to be *really* correct, the value of all identifiers is a reference. But hey, I'm over it. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, great point, I didn't know that - I thought JS had the concept of (pure) values, but I guess not.

Comment: Just as an addendum, it's interesting (and confusing) that `Number(something)` returns a number VALUE whereas `new Number(something)` returns a number OBJECT. These are some of the downfalls of not having a superclass (like `Object` in Java).

Answer (score 20):

This is because `50` by itself is a Number *value*, whereas you are returning a Number *object*.

```
alert(typeof 50); // number
alert(typeof (50).abs()); // object
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pkkaq/

Section 4.3.21 of the [ECMAScript reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf):

> A Number object is created by using
>   the Number constructor in a new
>   expression, supplying a Number value 
>   as an argument. The resulting object
>   has an internal property whose value
>   is the Number value. A Number object
>   can be  coerced to a Number value by
>   calling the Number constructor as a
>   function.

In other words, a Number *value* cannot be strictly equal to a Number *object*.

```
typeof 50 === typeof new Number(50) //--> false; number != object
```

The reason why `(-50).abs()` works as expected is because it is being multiplied by `-1`. When a Number *object* is multiplied by a Number *value* it becomes a Number *value*. In this case, if the parameter is positive, the object is simply returned untouched, causing an *object* to be returned.

Here is a fix for your method, according to the quoted reference above:

```
Number.prototype.abs = function () {
    return Number(this >= 0 ? this : this * -1);
};
```

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler Maybe you can explain why `typeof (-50).abs()` returns 'number'?

Comment: Because when a Number *object* is multiplied by a Number *value* it becomes a Number *value*. If the parameter is already positive, the object is simply returned untouched.

Comment: `return this >= 0 ? this * 1 : this * -1;` works just fine. I tried that right after I asked the question, but I figured it's a good chance to give someone a little more reputation, and this actually explains why, which is helpful for the future so I don't fall into this trap again. Congrats, you're a nerd. :)

Comment: You're essentially correct +1, but you still don't answer why `this` is an object (which is, I think, the real question here). See my answer for why `this` is an object.

Comment: The simple solution is: `return Math.abs(this);`

Comment: @RobG: Seriously? That does not answer the question one bit. The point of the question was *why* his version of `abs` was not working as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Triple equals (===) checks type as well as value to ensure they are equal. It fails for the same reason that `new Number(5) !== 5` and `new String("Text") !== "Text"`, in that they're different types. However, when you're using your negative absolute value, you're performing a mathematical computation which is outputting a raw number, and not a number object. Due to this, the type check matches and it's true.

Answer (score 5):

`Math.abs(-50) === 50` works everywhere. So you could rewrite Number.prototype.abs to:

```
Number.prototype.abs = function () {
    return Math.abs(this);
};
```

I suppose. Tested `Math.abs(50) === 50` in IE9 and Chrome 11, both: `true`

Other ways to make (50).abs() === 50 using your method may be:

```
return this >= 0 ? this.valueOf() : this * -1;
return this >= 0 ? this * 1 : this * -1;
```

So you extension doesnt return an object (this) when > 0, but a number value.

But I would advise to just use the already available `Math.abs` method, in which case you can be sure that `Math.abs(50) === 50;` returns `true` and you avoid an unnecessary [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

For completeness: from the selected answer it follows that using `strict` would be a solution too.

Comment: Or even as: 'Number.prototype.abs = Math.abs' however, mucking about with core Javascript objects is very much frowned upon.

Comment: I already use strict mode. It worked in Chrome and Firefox, because they're the only of the 5 that support strict mode.

Comment: @Rob Raisch: That will not work, since `Math.abs` uses the first argument instead of the `this` value.

Answer (score 2):

The === returns true if both operands are of the same TYPE and equal in value as well.  I'll bet the implementations where it's returning false are returning a float instead of an int.

Comment: Wrong.  Javascript doesn't have an integer type.

Comment: Close though...  I think Jerenmy Heiler nails it though.

Comment: Javascript variables don't have any type, their values do.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem is your abs method. "this" in your function is an object, so when you return "this" it is a type of object. "this"* -1 is converted to number by javascript.

As people have suggested, using Math.abs() is probably the best way to go.

If you really want your function to work then do this:

```
Number.prototype.abs = function () {
    return this >= 0 ? parseInt(this) : this * -1;
};
```

Of course, this is assuming you're working with integers only.

Comment: :( Bad answer. `parseInt` is `eval`.

Comment: heh, you're right, didn't had that in mind when I type up the code.